Switch to php8.2 in .htaccess not working
I just try to switch from php7.4 to php8.2 changing .httaccess like this:
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php82 .php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

I am not succeeding. This is output of
sudo update-alternatives --config php


.htaccess is stored in same folder info.php is stored. Why is php8.2 not version being used for? I want to switch between different php versions depending on code being used for different subdomains. This is output of info.php:

Here is an extraction of Vhost:
<Directory /var/www/testshop.leitner-sales.at>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>


AddHandler needs the FileInfo override allowed, check if that is the case in your server config.

update-alternatives is a tool for managing symlinks (short-cuts), like when you type just "php" on the command-line. It doesn't have any way of managing multiple simultaneous versions in Apache, or any interaction with configuration files like .htaccess

Oh man, always these unnecessary comments. update-alternatives just has been published showing up ,that both php versions have been installed!

Not sure if you understood what @IMSoP wrote.

The problem is that update-alternatives is only going to show you which command-line versions of PHP are installed, when what matters is what versions of the Apache PHP handler are installed, and activated so that Apache can make use of them. apt list --installed | grep libapache2-mod-php is probably more relevant, along with ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep php

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow and good on you for updating, a little late to the party tho ;P You'll love php ^8.
Now, typically, php can be run in multiple ways like CLI and GUI (there are actually many more, but off-topic), which is the server context. In a stock installation of apache with php the users request is forwarded to PHP's .so file. This file is actually the artifact of compiling PHP directly from its source code written in C.
This is all to say if you have not restarted apache that new compiled handler may not be found.
Let's dig in deeper. You're adding a handler in apache to the .htaccess file, which is cleaver I've never seen that, but this handlers definition (aka the executable it points to) is defined in the server config. Typically httpd.conf. Many things can not be added to the .htaccess but must be loaded at startup, not call-time. When you type php in the command line you are actually using a different executable php than apache should. Thus your php-cli vs php-cgi.
# In httpd.conf or a configuration file included by it
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php
    Action application/x-httpd-php74 /cgi-bin/php74-cgi
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php8.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php80 .php
    Action application/x-httpd-php80 /cgi-bin/php80-cgi
</IfModule>


Look at my answer above, please. Ur suggestion is ineffective. I implemented ur suggestion both, in .htaccesa and in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf. PHP8.2 will not be used! There is no httpd.conf in any folder
